# HTML Select box returning null in Servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have an HTML form that looks like this:

```
   <form action="UploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="fileUpload" size="50" />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />

            <select name="options">
                <option value="public">Public File</option>
                <option value="locker">Locker File</option>
            </select>
    </form>
```

I want the user to select a file and then select an option from the dropdown to choose where the file is saved to.

I am attempting to retrieve the value of the option using

```
String option = request.getParameter("options");
```

However, for some reason, the option is null, despite choosing an option.

Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after tearing through results on StackOverflow/Google.

The issue comes into play with the `"multipart/form-data"` enctype attribute on the form element. Whenever you call `.getParameter` with that enctype, it will return null.

For a solution, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729777/servlet-get-parameter-from-multipart-form-in-tomcat-7) question/answer