# multipart form data getParameter doesn't work

Tags: java, html, forms, file, servlets

I am trying to send files with some text to the server using HTML like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>File Upload:</h3>
  Select a file to upload: <br />
  <form action="UploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
    <input type="hidden" name="someText" value="3" />
    <input type="text" value="Upload File" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Now I'm trying to get it in servlet using request.getParameter("someText"). but it returns null? any suggestions or solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729777/servlet-get-parameter-from-multipart-form-in-tomcat-7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Servlet get parameter from multipart form in tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729777/servlet-get-parameter-from-multipart-form-in-tomcat-7)

Comment: Show us your UploadServlet class code